# How to set minimum required iOS version?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an IOS project which i had set the IOS Deployment Target to 4.3 under Targets > Build Settings. I have Uploaded it to iTunes connect and now it says Requires IOS 6 or later. Also the valid architectures are : armv7 armsv7.

Comment: `Target` -> `iOS Application target` -> `Summary` -> `Deployment target`, and the *valid architectures* are `armv7`, `armv7s` and `armv6`. it have to work.

Comment: Form the command line, use `-mios-version-min=6.0`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The minimum version supported of your app is set in the summary section of your project. Look for `deployment target`. If you specify `4.3` for example in that field it means that you are supporting all version starting from `4.3`. Double check your settings.

Comment: hello thanks you for you response.. but i have crossed checked . Under Targets - Summary tab the Devices are set to Universal (normal since my applications supports both iphone & ipad ) & deployment sections is set to 4.3

Comment: That is weird i am currently supporting 5.1 and above in an app i recently published and there was no other extra step than the one i mentioned. Where did u check the supported version in iTunes connect ? (View Details -> Binary Details ?)

Answer (score 10):

The deployment target is there in the project summary page of xcode

[image: Set the value here]

Comment: Should I want to set it in Project also ? Or just setting in Target is enough ?

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have set the minimum deployment target to iOS 13 This means your application is compatible with iOS 13 and above devices.

The application won't run on below 13.0 devices but can run on any iOS version greater than iOS 13.0

[image]