# Setting the Minimum iOS version in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, cocoonjs

I'm fairly new to Xcode as I use CocoonJS to build my HTML5 iPhone game but I want to know how to *correctly* set the minimum iOS version. I've set my deployment target to 8.0 and did a clean and then a build but when I submit to the app store it says the minimum iOS version is 6.0.

The next thing I tried was manually updating this value in the info.plist but then I get an invalid binary in iTunes Connect saying

> Minimum OS Version Mismatch - The minimum OS version (LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS) in the binary ('6.0') for architecture ('armv7') differs from the MinimumOSVersion ('8.0') in the Info.plist

How do I update the minimum iOS version correctly without screwing up my binary? I've checked other threads but they all just say to update just the deployment target.

Comment: What version do you want as minimum, 6.0 or 8.0?

Comment: Are you compiling against the latest SDK?  Which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: I want to set it to 8.0, I'm using the latest version of XCode. I'm not sure which SDK I'm using. I'm at work and it's on my personal computer but I think it's the latest one (I'll double check when I get home)

Comment: Form the command line, use `-mios-version-min=6.0`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set minimum required Ios version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276220/how-to-set-minimum-required-ios-version)

Answer (score 32):

Assuming you're building against the 8.x SDK, and you have set the deployment target to 8.x or higher, that'll be enough.

However, I'd imagine you set the deployment target the wrong place in Xcode. You'll need to set it under your *Project* and not under your *Target*. Alternatively, if you have a `.xcconfig` file, you can change it by setting

```
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 8.1
```

If you don't have a `.xcconfig`, you can verify the deployment target, by opening your `project.pbxproj` file, and search for `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`, and check if it's set to your expected value.

Comment: CocoonJS cloud compiler gives me a .xcodeproj project so I can only seem to find the project.pbxproj inside. Everything looks fine here, all are set to 8.0. I've tried again with no luck. When I update the deployment target in the build settings should I expect to see the MinimumOSVersion in the Info.plist automatically change? Because it's not changing from 6.0 unless I manually change it. That seems a little weird to me (but I'm no iOS dev). In fact, the UIDevice family in the Info.plist still has both iPad and iPhone in there even though I set it to only iPhone in the build settings

Comment: We don't use `MinimumOSVersion` in our projects, and they're explicitly 8.x or higher when we deploy them to the app store.

Comment: Do you mean that they show up in iTunes Connect as 8.x or higher, or that they just get restricted in the app store itself? I've tried everything to get the MinimumOSVersion to update correctly but nothing seems to work. If the deployment target will restrict it anyway then I wouldn't really care

Comment: I don't know about iTunes Connect. It shows up in TestFlight being restricted to 8.x.

Comment: I can't remove the MinimumOSVersion itself or XCode has a conniption submitting to iTunes Connect. Is there a way to change the LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS setting manually?

Answer (score 30):

If you have Xcode `.xcworkspace` setup, say coming from ReactNative background, you would need to make sure:

- iOS Deployment Target set to `14.1` or whatever version you want to be minimum inside the **Project** > Build Settings > Deployment for all instances.
- iOS Deployment Target set to `14.1` or whatever version you want to be minimum inside the **Target** > Build Settings > Deployment for all instances.
- The deployment info in **Target** > General > Deployment Info is set to the minimum support version before the iPhone checkmark.

[image: iOS Minimum Deployment Info]

**To Verify** the minimum version is set properly.

- Archive the project.
- Validate and Distribute the Development version of the app.
- Locate the folder where the ipa was exported
- Open the .ipa with some archive utility software (example The unarchiver)
- Drag or Open the `Info.plist` in any code editor
- Search for `MinimumOSVersion` and check whether the minimum os version reflects the required version.

[image: MinimumOSVersion in Info.plist]

**Even after updating the Deployment Targets** the archive doesn't update with the set version, force exit xcode and re-open the workspace/project. Check if the settings from previous session were applied, look for every instance where `14.x` or whatever the current minimum version is present and update to the one required. Probably quit the Xcode once again and re-open. Generate the archive again and it should be reflect this time.