# ITMS-90725: SDK Version Issue

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios, fastlane

When I upload my build to testflight, I received this mail from the App store connect.

I think If I update my Xcode to 11 it gets resolved.

Can anyone clarify how to check the SDK version and how to update that?

```
  ITMS-90725: SDK Version Issue - This app was built with the iOS 12.1 SDK. 
Starting April 2020, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later, included in Xcode 11 or later.

    After you’ve corrected the issues, you can upload a new binary to App Store Connect.
```

Answer (score 4):

You're guess is right. You need to update Xcode installation on the Mac which uploads the Testflight builds.

If it's a CI machine or some kind of cloud build service like `Bitrise`, you have to update/select a newer Xcode version. If you're submitting Testflight builds from your local Mac, update Xcode locally.

You can check on Wikipedia, which iOS SDK was introduced in which Xcode version:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode

A quick summary:

```
Xcode version         iOS Base SDK included

8.0                   10.0
8.1                   10.1
8.2                   10.2
8.3                   10.3
8.3.3                 10.3.1

9.0                   11.0
9.1                   11.1
9.2                   11.2
9.3                   11.3
9.4                   11.4

10.0                  12.0
10.1                  12.1
10.2                  12.2
10.3                  12.4

11.0                  13.0
11.1                  13.1
11.2                  13.2

12.0                  14.0
12.1                  14.1
12.2                  14.2
12.3                  14.3
12.4                  14.4
12.5                  14.5

13.0                  15.0
13.1                  15.0
13.2                  15.2
13.3                  15.4
```

Every Xcode release is packed with a specific version of iOS Base SDK. You can't choose which Base SDK you want to use, only that particular version is available.

For example in `Xcode 11.1` you can only use `iOS 13.1` SDK. `iOS 13.0` or `iOS 13.2` SDK is not available.

**Note:** While you're picking the latest SDK with Xcode updates to access new features, you can still use for example iOS 10.0 `Deployment Target` in your project to support older devices.

Comment: Thank you for Bitrise hint, you save the day !
For others : Workflow Editor > Stack & Machines

Answer (score 1):

If your message is missing the version in the first mention of IOS SDK in the error message, you may be experiencing an Apple bug like I did.

I received this error even thought I had the correct versions.

I changed nothing (except the build number) and resubmitted and it worked.

Here was the error I received:

> ITMS-90725: SDK Version Issue - This app was built with the iOS SDK.
> As of June 30, 2020, all apps for iPhone or iPad must be built with
> the iOS 13 SDK or later, included with Xcode 11 or later.

Comment: On build number 4 (without any changes) it went finally through.

Comment: Searching how to set SDK version in XCode, this post made me realize that I needed to check in Bitrise configuration : Workflow > Stacks & Machines tab ;)

Answer (score 0):

We were facing the same issue with our Github CI/CD deployment workflow to TestFlight, and this is how it was fixed:

- update *.yml workflow:

```
jobs:
  deploy_testflight_ios:
    name: Deploy TestFlight - iOS
    runs-on: macos-latest

...

        env:
          // https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20910#issuecomment-1338965999
          ITMSTRANSPORTER_FORCE_ITMS_PACKAGE_UPLOAD: false
          XCVERSION: "14.1.0"
...
```

- update ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist with the current MinimumOSVersion

```
  <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
  <string>1.0</string>
  <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/68146788/10708345
  <string>16.1</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

- update ios/Gemfile.lock with the current fastlane version

```
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/73771951/10708345
    fastlane (2.210.0)
```

- update ios/Podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955114/10708345
    target.build_configurations.each do |build_configuration|
        build_configuration.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64 i386'
    end
    # Start of the permission_handler configuration
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      # https://stackoverflow.com/a/75883614/10708345
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '14.0'
      # https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController/issues/533#issuecomment-1245332415
      config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, After upgrading the Xcode the error not received for me