# Xcode 14: Could not find transporter at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, fastlane

I simply trying to upload build with fastlane to itunesconnect, but I have an error:

> Could not find transporter at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/. Please make sure you set the correct path to your Xcode installation.

This is how it looks in console (click for larger images):

[image]

[image]

and in code:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Update Fastlane to [2.210.0](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/releases/tag/2.210.0), they recently fixed this by migrating from Transporter to altool.

Comment: I can see `fastlane 2.210.0 is available. You are on 2.180.1.`. But when I update everything with `brew update fastlane` and run my lane again, there is still the same info: `fastlane 2.210.0 is available. You are on 2.180.1.`. Why?

Comment: If you're using fastlane installed from homebrew, I guess the right command to update it is `brew upgrade fastlane`.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk I found that doesn't work too. but when i run `which fastlane` get `/Users/**/.gem/bin/fastlane`, so I run `gem install fastlane` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Updating Fastlane is not necessary needed to fix the issue. If you upgraded to Xcode 14, iTMSTransporter is no longer included in Xcode 14.0, you can manually download and install it here: https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/#/apdA3ae5a8b0?sub=apdA687d545d
Run the build again and it will work.

Comment: This works for issue caused by Xcode 14 upgrade