# How to manually set the minimum version of watchOS to 9 and iOS to 16 in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swiftui-navigationstack, minimumosversion

I am wanting to use navigation stack for my watch app but when building I keep getting the error `"'NavigationStack' is only available in iOS 16.0 or newer"`

I understand I can simply wrap my code using `if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {}` and do the same for watchOS 9 respectively. However, I want the app to just not even be available for download on anything older. That way, there should be no need for these wrappers since this code will never be run on anything older.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set minimum required iOS version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276220/how-to-set-minimum-required-ios-version)